# How to print its Output of this if its killed or not

Tags: shell

*I'm taking input argument as port no. and try to kill all process running on it.*

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep $1 |  grep -v -F 'grep'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
-9

echo Killed the process
```

**Output i get:**

```
./killport 4504
Killed
```

regardless of it's killed or not

Answer (score 0):

> The xargs utility exits with a value of 0 if no error occurs.  If
>   utility cannot be found, xargs exits with a value of 127, otherwise if
>   utility cannot be exe-
>        cuted, xargs exits with a value of 126.  If any other error occurs, xargs exits with a value of 1.

I think the issue here is that you are using kill inside of xargs so even if you were checking the return value with chaining `&&` etc, it will still exit with a 0... so you can't detect it that way...

as written it will always print `Killed the process`

Comment: its just printing "Killed" ... not even the whole sentence

/scripts>./killport 4504
Killed

Comment: ps -ef | grep $1 |  grep -v -F 'grep'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
-9 


its killing process (-v is to not kill grep it self )

Comment: but ps doesn't print the command as grep, it prints it as whatever you call it  `501 52271 52195   0 12:09PM ttys017    0:00.01 bash test.sh python`